# When does $\mathscr{R}(A) \cap \mathscr{C}(A) = \{\vec{0}\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A \in \mathbb{R^{n,n}}$, are there cases in which 
$$\mathscr{R}(A) \oplus \mathscr{C}(A)=\mathscr{H},$$
where $\mathscr{R}(A) $ is the rows space of $A$ , $\mathscr{C}(A)$ is the columns space of $A$ and $\mathscr{H}$ is any vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$? In other words, when does $\mathscr{R}(A) \cap \mathscr{C}(A)={\vec{0}}$ ?

In this example it is true 
$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1&-2&4&1\\ 2&-3&9&-1\\1&0&6&-5\\2&-5&7&5 \end{bmatrix},$$
but in general?

I know that if $A$ is a square symmetric matrix then from rank-nullity $\mathscr{C}(A) \oplus \mathscr{N}(A) = \mathbb{R^{n}}$ but I don't know what to say about this problem.

Comment: What are $\mathscr{R}(A)$ and $\mathscr{C}(A)$, and what are you asking about $\mathscr{R}(A) \oplus \mathscr{C}(A)$?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you'll want to notice is that one must have $m = n$ because otherwise the row space and column space are not subspaces of the same vector space. Furthermore, we know that $\dim\mathcal{R}(A) = \dim\mathcal{C}(A)$ so we must also have that $n$ and $m$ are even.

With these ideas in mind, then we must further have $\dim\mathcal{R}(A) = \dim\mathcal{C}(A) = \frac{n}{2}.$ The last issue of importance is that the row space and column space should be complimentary. Notice that the echelon form of the matrix you described is

$$\left(\begin{matrix} 1& 0& 6& -5\\0& 1& 1& -3\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right) $$

which so far satisfies the necessary conditions claimed above.

My guess that that $A$ will yield $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathcal{R}(A) \oplus \mathcal{C}(A)$ if and only if it reduces to something of the form

$$\left(\begin{matrix} 1& 0& a& b\\0& 1& c& d\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right) $$

where at least one of $a,b$  and one of $c,d$ be non-zero to ensure the row vectors be independent from the column vectors.

Finally, I'd like to say that there is probably a nicer classification here, but this one should also work.